# How to display products in php WHERE product_variant doesn't equal 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a products table in SQL . 
I want to display the products that do not have the value of 1 in the product_variant column of my table.

I have a product_variant column in my products table. I want to only display the products that do NOT have the value of 1 in product_variant.

```
$query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_variant != 1 ");
confirm($query);
```

nothing is happening.

Comment: What does `confirm()` do???

Comment: function confirm($result){

global $connection;

if(!$result) {

die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));


 }


}

Comment: The products do show up. But the query needs to be adjusted to only show specific products WHERE product_variant doesnt equal 1  ...

Comment: What is the column type of product_variant?

Comment: THanks that what i needed! but how to put it in a very long query concatenated? : 
$query = query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id = " . escape_string($_GET['id']) . " AND product_quantity >= 1  AND WHERE NOT product_variant = 1 ");

Comment: the product_variant column is data type: INT (11)

Comment: Don't concatenate SQL with PHP variables. Use prepared statements.

Comment: As @Dharman sais, prefer using prepared statements (with PDO for ex.). By using GET params in your query makes your application SQL injectable by the easy way.